# Compiling log4j2 trunk

Tags: log4j2

Getting the below error when doing "mvn clean install" from lo4j2 trunk. I want to take the latest log4j2 jars for my project.

```
[INFO] Apache Log4j 2 .................................... SUCCESS [0.574s]
[INFO] Apache Log4j API .................................. SUCCESS [5.993s]
[INFO] Apache Log4j Core ................................. FAILURE [4.718s]
[INFO] Apache Log4j 1.x Compatibility API ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j SLF4J Binding ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j to SLF4J Adapter ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Commons Logging Bridge ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Flume NG Bridge ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Tag Library .......................... SKIPPED    
[INFO] Apache Log4j JMX GUI .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Samples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Samples: Flume - Common .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Samples: Flume - Remote .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Samples: Flume - Embedded ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j 2 BOM ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j NoSQL ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4j Web .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Log4J Performance Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.202s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 29 12:52:27 MST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler  -plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project log4j-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/SmartOffers/Documents/log4j2-trunk/log4j/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/perftest/PerfTestDriver.java:[177,13] variable _averageOpsPerSec might already have been assigned
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is coming from the unit tests

You can skip the tests with enabling `-Dmaven.test.skip`

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: still failing : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project log4j-1.2-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:bundle:2.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:tests:2.0-SNAPSHOT in http://download.oracle.com/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oracleReleases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: why is it looking in http://download.oracle.com/maven seems dead.  Double check your POM, dependencies and repositories that should clear the issue.  you should post your pom.xml

Comment: this is a open source apache project, i will wait for that team to respond then.

Comment: Try http://download.java.net/maven/2/ instead.  Check the repos http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/dependencies.html

Comment: Looks like an issue with some test class. Was able to skip unit test and get the major jars using the command you provided. Accepting the answer.